# I get blank screen when connecting to router TP-Link

Tags: router

I was trying to configure router, I wrote the address of it, it sent me login form, I entered the credentials and it returned white screen like this:

[image]

It worked before, what could be the problem??

(also to mention, some time ago I changed wireless password, everything works ok, except I can't login)

Comment: try different browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, seems cable wasn't plugged well, so check the cables...

It's strange cos I was able to connect and it was giving me the login form, but couldn't get the rest...

Answer (score 1):

> **what could be the problem?**

Many things *could* be, including, but not limited to, the following:

Sometimes old router firmware relied on specific nonstandard quirks of older browsers and would not work with newer, more standards-compliant browsers.

Sometimes old router firmware relied on now-obsolete plugin technology such as ActiveX or on optional features such as Javascript which can be disabled in the browser configuration (e.g. for security).

Consequently, a browser upgrade (possibly happening in the background without your attention being drawn to it) might make the web-page unloadable.

Comment: I tried different browsers, always the same...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of blank page after credentials, with my TP-Link Archer cr700.

These browsers did not work: Chrome on Linux and macbook, Opera on Linux.

These browsers worked: Chrome on iPhone, Safari on iPhone, Safari on macbook, Firefox on Linux.